# Stripe checkout flow

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Trying to implement a cart with Stripe, but how should it look?

```
//checkout.php

$checkout_session = $stripe->checkout->sessions->create([
   'line_items' => [

    // foreach item listed in POST data,
    //  [],[],[],...

   ]
   'mode' => 'payment'
   'success_url' => $YOUR_DOMAIN . '/success.html',
   'cancel_url' => $YOUR_DOMAIN . '/cancel.html'
]);
```

Do I send checkout.php everything the customer wants in $_POST?
So on my domain I'm making a form?

Is there another way to do this, where the customer can add-to-cart and keep shopping on my site, then checkout?

Any words appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For what I understood you don't want to checkout every time the user selects a product? Maybe you could memorize in local storage the information for the cart, with the pricesID from Stripe and the single quantities. Then when the user decides to pay you can use the checkout form ( Stripe gives you a ready implementation for this ) and send all the informations of all the products the customer has in his/her own cart.

From the code you wrote probably you already checked it out, but giving a close look [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/how-checkout-works#session) you can see that you can add multiple items in list_items, so you can pass them from the front with the checkout integration and then send the request from the backend to sripe, exactly the way you wrote here.

If I misunderstood the problem here please tell me more, I'll be glad to help

Comment: stripe support says 'The shopping cart option can be added as a plugin for the Stripe checkout, but the option itself cannot be implemented with our platform.  However, you can contact our partners and get this option enabled on your website:...' > damn, PayPal builds a cart.  why wouldn't frontside stripe js only have 1 button:  buy-just-this-right-now ??

Comment: You can configure the "buy now" button if you build a product on stripe dashboard; when uou configure the single product it gives you the chance to have a prebuilt form that works just fine to buy that single product.
If you wanna build a cart logic instead, you can use the array + local storage approach instead, and then send a checkout with the array of the single products specifying the total amount to pay